# Remote Debugging with Jrebel

Tags: java, maven, jrebel

On my MAVEN_OPTS,I have this configuration

```
-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m  -javaagent:C:\Users\user\.IntelliJIdea14\config\plugins\jr-ide-idea\lib\jrebel\jrebel.jar
```

On my maven module, I run this code

```
 mvnDebug install -Prun,csoff -Dmaven.test.skip
Preparing to Execute Maven in Debug Mode
2015-05-28 18:05:15 JRebel:
2015-05-28 18:05:15 JRebel: A newer version '6.2.0' is available for download
2015-05-28 18:05:15 JRebel: from http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/download/
2015-05-28 18:05:15 JRebel:
2015-05-28 18:05:15 JRebel:
2015-05-28 18:05:15 JRebel: '-noverify' missing, changing/adding/removing constructors will not be enabled!
2015-05-28 18:05:15 JRebel:
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
2015-05-28 18:05:15 JRebel: Contacting myJRebel server ..
2015-05-28 18:05:17 JRebel:
2015-05-28 18:05:17 JRebel:  #############################################################
2015-05-28 18:05:17 JRebel:
2015-05-28 18:05:17 JRebel:  JRebel Legacy Agent 6.1.3 (201504281742)
2015-05-28 18:05:17 JRebel:  (c) Copyright ZeroTurnaround AS, Estonia, Tartu.
2015-05-28 18:05:17 JRebel:
2015-05-28 18:05:17 JRebel:  Over the last 2 days JRebel prevented
2015-05-28 18:05:17 JRebel:  at least 6 redeploys/restarts saving you about 0.2 hours.
2015-05-28 18:05:17 JRebel:
2015-05-28 18:05:17 JRebel:  Licensed to John Snow (using myJRebel).
2015-05-28 18:05:17 JRebel:
2015-05-28 18:05:17 JRebel:
2015-05-28 18:05:17 JRebel:  #############################################################
2015-05-28 18:05:17 JRebel:
```

Whenever I change a class located on another module(which is the dependency of the currently app) I open another terminal and execute `mvn compile`.  however it is not reloading

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Make sure that the other module's artifact contains `rebel.xml` with correct paths. Otherwise, enable logging as per [JRebel manual](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/learn/sending-log/) and send it to support@zeroturnaround.com.